# Взаимный include и определение структур и классов

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Здравствуйте! 
Есть проект, структура которого примерно такая (дальше код на с, внизу на c++):

**a.h**

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"

struct a_t
{
    char *f1;
    char *f2;

    int f3;
    int f4;

    // ...
};

typedef struct a_t a;

a generate_a()
{
    a ret;
    make_b_in_a(&ret);
    make_c_in_a(&ret);
    // ...
    return ret;
}

void print_a(a to_print)
{/* ... */}

#endif
```

**b.h**

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "a.h"

struct b_t
{
    int f1;
    int f2;
    int f3;

    // ...
};

typedef struct b_t B;

void make_b_in_a(a *obj)
{/* ... */}

#endif
```

**c.h**

```
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

#include "a.h"

struct c_t
{/* ... */};

typedef struct c_t c;

void make_c_in_a(a *obj)
{/* ... */}

#endif
```

**c.h**

```
#include "a.h"

int main()
{
    a test = generate_a();
    return 0;
}
```

При попытке скомпилировать эти четыре файла:

```
gcc main.c -o main.exe
```

получаю ошибки:

```
In file included from a.h:4:0,
                 from main.c:1:
b.h:17:18: error: unknown type name 'a'
 void make_b_in_a(a *obj)
                  ^
In file included from a.h:5:0,
                 from main.c:1:
c.h:11:18: error: unknown type name 'a'
 void make_c_in_a(a *obj)
                  ^
In file included from main.c:1:0:
a.h: In function 'generate_a':
a.h:23:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'make_b_in_a' [-Wimplicit-fu
nction-declaration]
  make_b_in_a(&ret);
  ^
a.h:24:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'make_c_in_a' [-Wimplicit-fu
nction-declaration]
  make_c_in_a(&ret);
  ^
```

Я думал, что `typedef` может работать в пределах файла, но замена `a` на `a_t` не помогла.

Как заставить такой проект скомпилироваться?

P. S. : предупреждая ваши вопросы: реализации всех функций лежат в отдельных `.c` файлах, компилирую так: `gcc *.c -o main.exe`.

---

Проверил, будет ли работать такая конструкция в с++.

**a.h**

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "b.h"

class a
{
public:
    b *f;
    a()
    {
        f = new b();
    }
};
#endif
```

**b.h**

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "a.h"

class b
{
public:
    a *f;

    b()
    {
        f = new a();
    }
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "a.h"

int main()
{
    a test();
    return 0;
}
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
  a *f;
  ^
b.h: In constructor 'b::b()':
b.h:13:3: error: 'f' was not declared in this scope
   f = new a();
   ^
b.h:13:11: error: expected type-specifier before 'a'
   f = new a();
```

И это, на самом деле, понятно, так как если скомпилировать с ключом `-E`, мы получим такой файл (лишнее убрано):

```
class b
{
public:
 a *f;

 b()
 {
  f = new a();
 }
};

class a
{
public:
 b *f;
 a()
 {
  f = new b();
 }
};


int main()
{
 a test();
 return 0;
}
```

Вероятно, нужно как-то предопределить `a` для `b`. Как это сделать в c++, и, желательно в c.

Answer (score 1):

Исправленный b.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "a.h"

typedef struct a_t a;

struct b_t
{
    int f1;
    int f2;
    int f3;

    // ...
};

typedef struct b_t B;

void make_b_in_a(a *obj)
{/* ... */}

#endif
```

Comment: В С не бывает using.

Comment: Не заметил что это простой С